# Connecting Android via wifi to Wifly RN-XV RN-171 using Access Point (soft AP) mode not working

Tags: java, android, tcp, udp, wireless-networking

I hope somebody has encountered this problem and knows how to fix it.  I purchased a Roving Networks RN-XV module to communicate directly with an Android device.  I thought it would be perfect because my project requires direct connection between the Android and my Arduino.  I have the RN-XV set in AP mode, and my Android phone is able to connect to it as if it were connecting to a router.  However, the UDP/TCP messages I send it do not show up.  I know there is not a problem with the configuration of the RN-XV because I have used my iPod and an iPhone to connect and send UDP/TCP and it works every time.  However, when I change modes on the RN-XV to connect to my home router, and my Android sends messages to the RN-XV via the router, it works fine.  Does anybody know of a problem with sending messages from an Android to the RN-XV in Access Point mode?  I have tried it on two Android devices, although they are older.  One is running 2.2.3, and the other is running 2.3.  Could this be a problem?

Answer (score -1):

I have had the same issue, using moto droid 2 running 2.3.4.
Reported to RN on firmware version 242 and Aug build of 245, still exists on Oct 2 build of 245 firmware.
RN response on Aug 8:
"We have not seen this behavior, but have not tested with this particular phone. It could be an issue with the phone itself, or the version of Android OS it is running. Either way, there isn't much we can do to diagnose and resolve this issue."

Comment: The question " Does anybody know of a problem with sending messages from an Android to the RN-XV in Access Point mode?" was answered.

Comment: Sorry, hit return too quickly. Please file a bug report with Microchip. I filed another report yesterday and supplied them pcap files taken inside my rooted phone showing the non-responsiveness of the rn-171 to pings and attempts to create tcp connections. The module works fine in adhoc mode to the Droid2 VZ (which supports adhoc natively) and also if rn-171 associated with an external access point. File a ticket, more people that exhibit the problem better chance of getting it fixed. http://www.microchip.com/support/List.aspx